# Delay in the 0, 4 and 6 keys on the numpad on Ubunutu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, numpad

After upgrading to Ubuntu 14.04, the <kbd>0</kbd>, <kbd>4</kbd> and <kbd>6</kbd> keys in my numpad suddenly respond only after being pressed for about a second. The rest of the numpad is fine, as well as the <kbd>0</kbd>, <kbd>4</kbd> and <kbd>6</kbd> above the letters.
My computer is a laptop (Vaio). I checked the slow keys option in the universal settings, that's not it.

Update: Turns out this problem applies only to my main (administer) acount. It doesn't happen in the login screen or a guest session.